# Determining the output impedance of a part of a circuit with negative feedback

Tags: small-signal, negative-feedback

I designed an active discrete baxandall volume control for my project.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fngGc7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R*(a-1) and R*(a) are supposed to be a potentiometer, *a* being the amount of rotation (0 to 1).
While designing the circuit I wasn't sure how to choose an appropriate value for R1 to match impedances with the output impedance looking into node n1 since the current through R*(a-1) should be equal to the current through R*a so that the volume control is working right. Now the circuit seems to be working just fine but because I don't want to just randomly choose a big resistor value I tried calculating the small signal ouput impedance looking into n1 and wanted to ask if my approach / outcome is valid or not. It's especially the negative feedback which confuses me.

**My approach:**

I broke the circuit down into this simplified small signal model by assuming very large input impedance looking into the base of Q1 and modeling the emitter follower Q3 as a small signal voltage controlled voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD5NAy.png)</sup>

*v1* is the "test voltage" at node n1. The voltage source to the right is a voltage controlled voltage source (*A* is the absolute value gain of the transistor stage **with** negative feedback)

Now I tried to find the ratio of *v1* to the current flowing into the circuit:

$$
i_{in} = i_{R_{1-a}} + i_{R_{a}} = i_{R_{1-a}} + i_{R_2} + i_{s} = \frac{v_1}{R_{1-a}} + \frac{-A \cdot v_1}{R_2} + i_s = \frac{v_1}{R_{1-a}} + \frac{-A \cdot v_1}{R_2} + \left( \frac{v_1 - (-A \cdot v_1)}{R_a} - \frac{-A \cdot v_1}{R_2} \right) = v_1 \cdot \left(\frac{1 + A}{R_{a}} + \frac{1}{R_{1-a}}\right)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow Z_{out} = R_{out} = \frac{1}{\frac{1+A}{R_a} + \frac{1}{R_{1-a}}}
$$

My question is simply if my analysis is right or not. And if it's wrong how would you correctly calculate the output impedance of such a circuit?

Thanks in advance and excuse me if my english isn't that well.

EDIT: Error in the schematic.

Comment: First ... Simulate and measure by applying the definition "output impedance" ... to have an idea of behavior. Then calculate ... for checking assumption.

Comment: Something weird on Q1 base ?

Comment: Yeah R1 goes to GND. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

> My approach:

If it seems to be "right", you can now check it. EE&O.

Determining output impedance can be, sometimes, very surprising, without first being sure that the circuit can "work" ...

So, I tried first choosing components and adding one "forgotten" resistor.
After checking DC values, I calculated "gain" vs "a".

[image]

Then calculated Zout as usual. Zout= Vo(load "open")/ Iload (load "shorted")

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! But i am refering to the output impedance of node n1 for choosing a right value for R1 and not the output impedance of the whole circuit.